# "Get down on one's level" or "get down to one's level"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I've heard native speakers say something like “get down on their level”. I am wondering if it's OK to say "get down to their level"?

"Get down on one's level" or "get down to one's level"?

Comment: I have heard "come down to my level".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a native speaker. However, I've heard many people saying "Come down **to** one's level". Say an instructor who teaches high school classes has been assigned to take a session in the third grade. Now on understanding how the students cannot follow the instructor as he is taking classes is his regular style, the principle goes to him and tells him :

> Mr.Jones, they are third graders. They take time to understand a topic. You've got to **get down to their level** and teach them slowly.

Alternatively, I've seen people using *"Sink down to their level too"*. This is usually used in a negative way :

> I never thought he would **sink down to this level**.

This is used more in a moral sense when the subject does something morally inappropriate.

Mark Twain once said:

> *"Never argue with stupid people, they will drag you down to their level and then beat you with experience"*.

I've also seen in many places, where people tend to use "on". So that is also not incorrect.